VBA: Loop through column values and store
I have constructed a financial model in excel, but want to know the sensitivity of a large set of assumptions. I have a tab of assumptions, which feeds into the model (col D8:D235), in the same sheet, I have made some alterations of these assumptions (Col M : Col R).
I basically want to replace the values in col D with the values in each of these columns in a loop, and save the corresponding output values.
Within a for-loop, I would like to change the values in column D of the assumption sheet with column M, N, O, P, etc.., to retrieve output values which are created in the "Output" sheet in I28:I57, which I would subsequently like to store in column K, L, etc. before replacing the values in the assumption sheet (column D), with the next set of input values.
I have zero knowledge with VBA, so I was hoping someone could help me out.
To illustrate, I think I now correctly call out the columns which are involved, but have no clue how to write the 'for-loop' in VBA.
Sub SensitivityAnalysis()
    'Define variables
    Dim inputVariables As Range
    Dim inputSet As Range
    Dim initialVariables As Range
    Dim Output As Range
    Dim outputTable As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    
    
    'Set input and output ranges
    Set inputVariables = Worksheets("Assumption sheet").Range("D8:D235")
    Set inputSet = Worksheets("Assumption sheet").Range("M8:R235")
    Set Output = Worksheets("Output sheet").Range("I28:I57")
    Set outputTable = Worksheets("Output sheet").Range("K28:P57")

    For i = 1:6
          inputVariables.clear()
          inputVariables = inputSet(i) 
          outputTable(i) = Output
End Sub

Thanks in advance.
I tried writing a for loop, but failed to do so

I am afraid that only reading your question and looking to the code we cannot understand what you really try accomplishing... Please better explain which is your goal. Or maybe you will edit your question showing a picture of existing and another one showing the processing result.

Tried clarifying!

You made now a little light, but still not clear enough... So, you need a code to iterate between all cells in  "D8:D235", then, for each such cell to iterate between columns "M:R" and replace the cell value with each iterated columns on the respective row. Now, what logic to be applied to save the Output? You probably have some formulas in "Output sheet", Range("I28:I57") but how to interpret them not knowing what the formula involves? In "Assumption" sheet there are 228 rows and in the "Output" sheets only 30. You should explain in details what is to be done, on the output issue

To iterate only by columns and change all values from "Assumption" sheet from D:D with corresponding values from the iterated column and then save the output from 'Output' (the whole column) in the corresponding iterated column of outputTable? I mean, in K:K for M:M, L:L for N:N? Or how? The iteration itself is simple, but a piece of code should do something based on a specific logic...

Sorry, let me clarify further. In column D I have the initial input saved. Other sheets get values from this column to make calculations, which are then displayed in the Output sheet (column I, row 28:57). To allow to play with the input values, i have made alterations on the set of inputs of column D, and saved these in columns M to R. I now want to iteratively replace the initial values in column D with these values (so first col M, then col N, etc.), and save the output (which is calculated in col I, and store these in col K, then col L, etc.). Hope this clarifies everything!

Can you confirm that the scenario I tried in my (last) above comment is correct? If not, what is it necessary to be clarified? I have some time and I will start preparing a piece of code based on this scenario...

Please, test the code I pasted and confirm (or infirm) that it does what you need. If it does not, please better clarify the scenario to be taken in consideration by the code...

Please, test the next piece of code. It iterates between all columns of inputSet, copy each column overwriting existing in inputVariables, calculates the output sheet and saves the output in the corresponding column:
Sub ProcessAssumptions()
 Dim WB As Workbook, wsAss As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet, inputVariables As Range, inputSet As Range
 Dim Output As Range, outputTable As Range, i As Long
 
 Set WB = ActiveWorkbook 'use here the workbook you need
 Set wsAss = WB.Worksheets("Assumption sheet")
 Set wsOut = WB.Worksheets("Output sheet")
 
 Set inputVariables = wsAss.Range("D8:D20") ' wsAss.Range("D8:D235")
 Set inputSet = wsAss.Range("M8:R20") ' wsAss.Range("M8:R235")
 
 Set Output = wsOut.Range("I28:I32") 'wsOut.Range("I28:I57")
 Set outputTable = wsOut.Range("K28:P32") 'wsout.Range("K28:P57")
 
 'Iterate between inputSet columns and do processing:
 For i = 1 To inputSet.Columns.count
    inputVariables.value = inputSet.Columns(i).value 'copy the inputSet as value, not as formula
    wsOut.Calculate     'if other sheets are involved you should use WB.Calculate
    outputTable.Columns(i).value = Output.value      'save the output in the corresponding colummn
 Next i
 
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub


@Jonas de Boo Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need? If not, can you better explain what should it return? Does it return something in your workbook, at least?

Just tested it, works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Please, Did you tried before using VBA with TreeView object to build a complex hierarchy of parents-child data on a UserForm?

Why should I try that? If something interesting, why don't you post such an answer?
